# Huge number of query at a time and populate checkbox with data in view page

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have 365 numbers of queries like following. I had created this in raw PHP long time ago, but since I am using codeigniter now I want to keep the query thing inside my model.

Actually what I created was a calender with checkbox function to insert date into database and when I populated my checkboxes with those data I used the following script.

Now I am not sure how to do the exact same thing in Codeigniter as it follows the MVC structure. Could you please tell me if I want to achieve the same thing using codeigniter how my model and view would look like?

```
<--Query 1 january 01 -->

<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="<? echo"$year-01-01 "; ?>" <? include('connect.php');
$check = mysql_query("SELECT wdt FROM workingdayteacher WHERE date='$year-01-01' AND teachername='$teacherid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($check))
 {
  echo "checked=\"checked\""; 
  } ?> > Jan 01 

<--Query 2 January 02 -->

 <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="<? echo"$year-01-02 "; ?>" <? include('connect.php');
 $check = mysql_query("SELECT wdt FROM workingdayteacher WHERE date='$year-01-02' AND teachername='$teacherid'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($check))
  {
  echo "checked=\"checked\""; 
  } ?> > Jan 02

<--Query 3 January 03 -->
 <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="<? echo"$year-01-03 "; ?>" <? include('connect.php');
 $check = mysql_query("SELECT wdt FROM workingdayteacher WHERE date='$year-01-03' AND teachername='$teacherid'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($check))
 {
  echo "checked=\"checked\""; 
   } ?> > Jan 03
```

When I display the calender it looks like following. Thanks :)

[image]

## Edit

Now I am trying to achieve the same thing like this...

```
           <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="<? echo"2011-05-18"; ?>" <? 
        if (in_array("2011-05-18", $date))
        {
        echo "checked=\"checked\""; 
        } ?> > Jan 03
```

Now here this $date .. I have to get from my model via controller...

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter is MVC, that means you should put the querying data code in the Model, and the code to display things in the View.
So, first thing you should do is to come up with a structure with all the information you need in the view. In this case, an `array` representing year containing `arrays` representing days should do. That way, in the view you could check a date testing the contents of `$YOUR_ARRAY[$month][$day]`.

In your Model, you call the queries needed to populate this array.
In the Controller, you call the Model to obtain the array, and pass it to the view.

Your code in the view would look like (edit as appropriated):

```
<?php $arr_months = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ..., 'Dec'); ?>
<?php foreach($month in array_keys($YOUR_ARRAY)): ?>
    <?php foreach($month in array_keys($YOUR_ARRAY)): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" <?php if (isset($YOUR_ARRAY[$month][$day])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>><?php echo $arr_months[$month] . " " . $day; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And in your model, you could probably be done with one query only, something like this:

```
$YOUR_ARRAY = array(array()); // init your array
$result = mysql_query("SELECT wdt, date FROM workingdayteacher WHERE date LIKE '$year-%' AND teachername='$teacherid'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    list($year, $day, $month) = explode('-', $row['date']);
    $YOUR_ARRAY[int($month)][int($day)] = TRUE;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you eljunior for you reply. I have tried your script.. and probably I am doing something wrong which is why it is not working. I am trying some other way. However thank you very much for your effort. :)

Comment: You're welcome! My code is not complete to copy'n paste, though the main idea is there. You still have to understand exactly what each part is doing, before apply it to your code.

Comment: Ouch, I missed the delimiter in the explode call! Fixed it!

Comment: Thanks again eljunior. Could you please tell me how my model would look like if I want to get the result as an array like this- $a = array("one","two","three");   Please kindly check the edited portion of my post above. thanks  :)

Comment: you mean, the part to show "Jan 1", "Feb 2", etc? this is to do in the view, I fixed the code in my answer for it.

Comment: No, I am not using the script you posted earlier.. I was planning something new.. querying the data in the model and get the result as an array and get the array result in the view via controller and then check if the particular value exists in the array result... if then the check box will be checked otherwise not... So my question was how to query into the database so that i get the result as an array like... array("one","two","three"); ... sorry if i am bothering you..:)

Comment: ah! I understood now what you mean. Use `mysql_fetch_array()`: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

On the code, instead of this tediousness, why not go through 2 foreach loops, one for the months and one for the days, and keep checking whether the looping month and date matches any from the table, and show them.

Comment: He is saying (more or less): run ONE query to get all working days during the year for that particular teacher. Create an array of those dates, indexed by the date; foreach($query_results as $row) $teacherdays[$row->date]. Then create a simple array of dates for the entire year, and loop through that; foreach($days as $day) if(isset($teacherdays($day)) $selected = TRUE

Comment: Thanks permawash it has given me some idea now.. :0.